# Net core 3.1 - azure function: Could not load file or assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823'

Tags: c#, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1, csvhelper

I have an azure function based on .Net core 3.1, it uses CsvHelper package

Below is my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="27.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="3.1.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="3.1.25" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CrossCutting\CrossCutting.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DomainCore\DomainCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

However, I am getting the following error

> [2022-05-28T21:31:32.619Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while
> executing function: FileTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more
> errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or
> assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.)). System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred.
> (Could not load file or assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.). BusinessService: Could not load file or
> assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=27.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.

Comment: Hey  try solution of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633914/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-csvhelper-c-vs2019-csvhelper

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version you are using ?