# Identify duplicate from large file based on one field and remove record

Tags: c#, linq, ssis

I have a relatively large csv file, with a lot of columns. I need to read that file, and determine if there are multiple records with the same "Test File Name" field and only grab the first record (by date) and copy those to a new file, essentially removing the "duplicate". The records are not true duplicates as each record has different data but the same "Test File Name" so, the general "remove duplicates" methods are not working for me. The duplicates are few and far between, so I need to loop through all of the records and only grab the first one entered, which is determined by the "Date Time" field in the record.

I need only one of each "Test File Name"

[Duplicate Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QolUw.png)

[image: Identifying fields]

I tried a group by and order by but I am not sure I am doing it correctly, because it is not removing the second record.

Update: Let me clarify, the file is not THAT large, it's under a MB but there are thousands of records. I am attempting to do this process in a script task of an SSIS package. I apologize for my ignorance in posting here, and the subject matter in general. I am new to C# as I mostly work in SQL.

Comment: That image is barely readable.

Comment: Welcome to SO: please post your code

Comment: @Eldar Right-click > Open image in new tab

Comment: @auburg , I don't have code that works, so there's nothing to post. I tried a couple of linq suggestions I found using .Groupby() .Orderby() but it didn't work.

Comment: If file fits memory and order of records doesn't matter, you can try `GroupBy(item => item.TestFileName).Select(group => group.MinBy(item => item.DateTime))`

Comment: _"I don't have code that works,"_ if you had, you wouldn't be writing this question :D Anyway: posting the "best attempt that failed" is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "relatively large"? Is it large enough that you can't reasonably have all the csv records read into memory at the same time? I think why you are getting complex answers is because you seem to be suggesting that you can't filter in memory and so people are trying to come up with solutions that minimize reads and keeps only single records in memory at a time. If you knew that records with the same test file name are adjacent then you could do some simpler optimizations using a for or foreach loop.

Comment: It's not really THAT large. It's under a MB but will grow and this process will run daily. Again, I am new here, so I apologize for my ignorance. I am attempting to do this in a script task in an SSIS package.

Comment: And also is the Timestamp related to the position in the file? I mean: If you iterate lines from top (Start of file) to bottom (End of file), will a later instance of the same key have a later timestamp, earlier timestamp or is it going to be completely random?

Comment: Yes a later instance will have a later timestamp as in the screenshot. I just need the first record (earlier timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your input, I was finally able to use LINQ similar to @Dmitry's comment, with a different variation and it worked. I figured it might help someone else in the future so I wanted to post the solution.

```
            if (File.Exists(databasedatacsv))
            {
                //Read original file and remove duplicates
                var data = File.ReadAllLines(databasedatacsv)
                                    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                                    .Where(x => x[1] != "")
                                    .GroupBy(x => x[1])
                                    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y[2]).First());

                foreach(var item in data)
                {
                    string s = string.Join(",", item);
                    //Dump the data into a new CSV so we aren't modifying the original file
                    AppendPSFile(psdatabasedatacsv, s);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like below, would work for you. The idea is to read the CSV file line by line get the `FileName` field keep it in a `HashSet` and write a new CSV file that contains only one record per `FileName`:

```
var fileNameSet = new HashSet<string>();
using var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\file.csv"));
using var writer = new StreamReader("path\\to\newfile.csv"));
using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

csv.Read();
csv.ReadHeader();
while (csv.Read())
 {
        var @record = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
        var fileName = @record.FileName;
        var added = fileNameSet.Add(fileName)
        if(!added) continue;

        csvWriter.WriteRecord(@record);
        csvWriter.NextRecord(); 
  }
```

You may want to use `HashSet<int>` instead of string and change the `var fileName = record.FileName;` into `var fileName = record.FileName.GetHashCode();` that will consume less memory. This sample uses [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Comment: ["record"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) is a keyword and this does not account for the "update if newer" requirement if I am not missing something. (Not downvoting, just suggesting improvement)

Comment: Using the hashcode alone is not a good solution, since two different strings can have the same hashcode.

Comment: @Eldar - the hash code did not work in previous attempts because they are not true duplicates. The records have different data. There are only 2 fields that are identical. (Test File Name is the field I am concentrating on)

Comment: @Amanda: Mind that this answer does _not_ hash the whole line but only the filename field, which I would expect to be somewhat reliable.

Comment: I am getting errors when trying to add the CsvHelper     "Error: Could not load file or assembly 'CsvHelper, Version=30.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"  it doesn't like it.

Comment: @Amanda maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633914/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-csvhelper-c-vs2019-csvhelper) helps

Comment: Btw: `HasSet.Add` returns false if the element to add is already contained. So you could strip this down to one call to add  instead of contains check and then add ...

Comment: @Fildor nice catch, edited the answer accordingly.